# JPA - Mysterious Cascade on Updates

Tags: jpa, jboss, eclipselink, updates, cascade

Please bear with this long question, it's a difficult situation that's hard to describe.

We are seeing what I can only describe as mysterious cascade updates to our database from our JPA applcation.  The application is a batch processor.  We have three tables/entities with this type of relationship:

```
ObjectA has one to many on ObjectB
ObjectB has one to many on ObjectC
```

where ObjectA is a batch object, ObjectB is a container object that contains ObjectCs which actually need to processed.  We process the ObjectCs in the first ObjectB then those in the second ObjectB etc.  Only instances of ObjectA and ObjectC are actually updated in the database during processing.

We get the list of ObjectCs by executing a named query instead of by following the relationships because they need to be filtered.

ObjectA's status is updated at the beginning of the processing and at the end.  ObjectCs' statuses are updated as they are processed.

We are seeing that that the statuses for ObjectCs are being updated again to a previous (wrong) status but cannot figure our what is calling the update.  At first I thought it was cascading from ObjectA's status update, so I changed the cascade type on the entity classes to only casade on persist and not update.  They look like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "OBJECT_A")
@Cacheable(false)
public class ObjectA implements Serializable
{
    // bi-directional many-to-one association to OpticalReceiver
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, mappedBy = "objectA")

        private Set<ObjectB> objectBs;

    ....
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "OBJECT_b")
@Cacheable(false)
public class ObjectB implements Serializable
{
    // bi-directional many-to-one association to OpticalReceiver
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, mappedBy = "objectB")
    private List<ObjectC> objectCs;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to Batch
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private ObjectA objectA;

    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "OBJECT_b")
@Cacheable(false)
public class ObjectB implements Serializable
{
    // bi-directional many-to-one association to OpticalReceiver
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, mappedBy = objectB")
    private List<ObjectC> objectCs;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to Batch
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private ObjectA objectA;

    ...
}
```

However, we are still getting updates.  I added logging to our DataService class to see when it gets called.  Originally, I had a stack trace in them, but the update and create methods are not called when the "mystery" updates happen.  It looks like this:

In my data service object I have these methods:

```
public class DataService implements GenericService
{
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DataService.class);    

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "database")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public <T> T create(T t)
        throws IllegalArgumentException, EntityExistsException, PersistenceException
    {
        em.persist(t);
        logger.debug("Persisted objectType={} ({}) to database (Batch should cascade)", t.getClass().getSimpleName(), t);

        return t;
    }

    @Override
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public <T> T update(T t)
        throws IllegalArgumentException, PersistenceException
    {
        t = em.merge(t);
        logger.debug("Updated objectType={} ({}) to database (Batch should NOT cascade)", t.getClass().getSimpleName(), t);

        return t;
    }

    ...
}
```

We are only seeing the update and create method logging when expected.  We do not see them being called for the mystery update statements.  However we do see the SQL statements in the server.log file (using EclipsLink in JBoss EAP):

```
08:54:14,610 (EJB default - 6) UPDATE OBJECT_C SET CURRENT_STATE = ? WHERE ((ID = ?) AND (CHANGE_ID = ?))[2, 00:11:80:8d:71:be, CRQ000000000001]
08:54:19,283 (EJB default - 6) UPDATE OBJECT_C SET CURRENT_STATE = ? WHERE ((ID = ?) AND (CHANGE_ID = ?))[6, 00:11:80:8d:71:be, CRQ000000000001]

08:54:24,180 (EJB default - 7) UPDATE OBJECT_C SET CURRENT_STATE = ? WHERE ((ID = ?) AND (CHANGE_ID = ?))[2, 00:15:2f:2c:4d:f2, CRQ000000000001]
08:54:25,140 (EJB default - 7) UPDATE OBJECT_C SET CURRENT_STATE = ? WHERE ((ID = ?) AND (CHANGE_ID = ?))[6, 00:15:2f:2c:4d:f2, CRQ000000000001]

08:54:34,192 (EJB default - 8) UPDATE OBJECT_C SET CURRENT_STATE = ? WHERE ((ID = ?) AND (CHANGE_ID = ?))[2, 00:15:2f:53:c7:3a, CRQ000000000001]
08:54:35,115 (EJB default - 8) UPDATE OBJECT_C SET CURRENT_STATE = ? WHERE ((ID = ?) AND (CHANGE_ID = ?))[6, 00:15:2f:53:c7:3a, CRQ000000000001]

08:54:44,199 (EJB default - 9) UPDATE OBJECT_C SET CURRENT_STATE = ? WHERE ((ID = ?) AND (CHANGE_ID = ?))[2, 00:15:a4:ac:31:03, CRQ000000000001]
08:54:45,168 (EJB default - 9) UPDATE OBJECT_C SET CURRENT_STATE = ? WHERE ((ID = ?) AND (CHANGE_ID = ?))[6, 00:15:a4:ac:31:03, CRQ000000000001]

08:54:54,207 (EJB default - 10) UPDATE OBJECT_C SET CURRENT_STATE = ? WHERE ((ID = ?) AND (CHANGE_ID = ?))[2, 00:15:cf:09:1a:69, CRQ000000000001]
08:54:55,327 (EJB default - 10) UPDATE OBJECT_C SET CURRENT_STATE = ? WHERE ((ID = ?) AND (CHANGE_ID = ?))[6, 00:15:cf:09:1a:69, CRQ000000000001]

08:55:04,222 (EJB default - 1) UPDATE OBJECT_C SET CURRENT_STATE = ? WHERE ((ID = ?) AND (CHANGE_ID = ?))[2, 00:15:cf:1b:4f:33, CRQ000000000001]
08:55:04,802 (EJB default - 1) UPDATE OBJECT_C SET CURRENT_STATE = ? WHERE ((ID = ?) AND (CHANGE_ID = ?))[6, 00:15:cf:1b:4f:33, CRQ000000000001]

08:55:14,220 (EJB default - 2) UPDATE OBJECT_C SET CURRENT_STATE = ? WHERE ((ID = ?) AND (CHANGE_ID = ?))[2, 00:1d:ce:62:00:f6, CRQ000000000001]
08:55:15,876 (EJB default - 2) UPDATE OBJECT_C SET CURRENT_STATE = ? WHERE ((ID = ?) AND (CHANGE_ID = ?))[6, 00:1d:ce:62:00:f6, CRQ000000000001]

08:55:24,227 (EJB default - 4) UPDATE OBJECT_C SET CURRENT_STATE = ? WHERE ((ID = ?) AND (CHANGE_ID = ?))[2, 00:1d:d1:ed:64:09, CRQ000000000001]
08:55:24,814 (EJB default - 4) UPDATE OBJECT_C SET CURRENT_STATE = ? WHERE ((ID = ?) AND (CHANGE_ID = ?))[6, 00:1d:d1:ed:64:09, CRQ000000000001]

08:55:34,237 (EJB default - 3) UPDATE OBJECT_C SET CURRENT_STATE = ? WHERE ((ID = ?) AND (CHANGE_ID = ?))[2, 5c:57:1a:5f:11:d3, CRQ000000000001]

08:55:34,237 (EJB default - 5) UPDATE OBJECT_C SET CURRENT_STATE = ? WHERE ((ID = ?) AND (CHANGE_ID = ?))[2, 00:11:80:8d:71:be, CRQ000000000001]
08:55:34,240 (EJB default - 5) UPDATE OBJECT_C SET CURRENT_STATE = ? WHERE ((ID = ?) AND (CHANGE_ID = ?))[2, 00:15:2f:2c:4d:f2, CRQ000000000001]
08:55:34,242 (EJB default - 5) UPDATE OBJECT_C SET CURRENT_STATE = ? WHERE ((ID = ?) AND (CHANGE_ID = ?))[2, 00:15:2f:53:c7:3a, CRQ000000000001]
08:55:34,245 (EJB default - 5) UPDATE OBJECT_C SET CURRENT_STATE = ? WHERE ((ID = ?) AND (CHANGE_ID = ?))[2, 00:15:a4:ac:31:03, CRQ000000000001]
08:55:34,247 (EJB default - 5) UPDATE OBJECT_C SET CURRENT_STATE = ? WHERE ((ID = ?) AND (CHANGE_ID = ?))[2, 00:15:cf:09:1a:69, CRQ000000000001]
08:55:34,250 (EJB default - 5) UPDATE OBJECT_C SET CURRENT_STATE = ? WHERE ((ID = ?) AND (CHANGE_ID = ?))[2, 00:15:cf:1b:4f:33, CRQ000000000001]
08:55:34,252 (EJB default - 5) UPDATE OBJECT_C SET CURRENT_STATE = ? WHERE ((ID = ?) AND (CHANGE_ID = ?))[2, 00:1d:ce:62:00:f6, CRQ000000000001]
08:55:34,255 (EJB default - 5) UPDATE OBJECT_C SET CURRENT_STATE = ? WHERE ((ID = ?) AND (CHANGE_ID = ?))[2, 00:1d:d1:ed:64:09, CRQ000000000001]
08:55:34,257 (EJB default - 5) UPDATE OBJECT_C SET CURRENT_STATE = ? WHERE ((ID = ?) AND (CHANGE_ID = ?))[2, 5c:57:1a:5f:11:d3, CRQ000000000001]

08:55:35,161 (EJB default - 3) UPDATE OBJECT_C SET CURRENT_STATE = ? WHERE ((ID = ?) AND (CHANGE_ID = ?))[6, 5c:57:1a:5f:11:d3, CRQ000000000001]
```

The updates by thread `(EJB default - 5)` is the main BatchProcessor thread which runs the batch.  The other threads are stateless session beans created to process each ObjectC individually.

So, the mystery updates are being processed by the main thread.  We thought it may cascade when the final ObjectA update was done (even though the CascadeType is set not to) so took out the call to it.  But, the ObjectC updates still happen.

Does anyone have any advice on how to determine what is triggering these updates and/or how to stop them?

Comment: what is triggering them you can easily enough see by calling "(new Exception()).printStackTrace()" at your debug statement

Comment: We tried that and that method isn't called at all, so we can't get the stack trace.

Comment: Show the code being used in EJB default - 5, as something is reading in these entities and modifying them.  Merge is only needed when an entity is detached - if it isn't detached, changes will be picked up by the EntityManager when it is flushed or the transaction commits.

Comment: How do you tell the entity manager to update an object in the db if you don't use merge?

Comment: You only need to merge a detached entity.  If you change an object read in from an EntityManager, it is managed and that EntityManager will pick up those changes if it is associated to a transaction that commits